# Angular11 rxjs switchmap not working even when outer observable trigger

Tags: rxjs, angular11

I am trying out following which basically needs to trigger everytime a filter gets changed. Cananyone please help what am i doing wrong with using higher order observables.

Working version:

```
this.filterservice.registerFilters({
                key: this.FILTERS_KEY,
                filters: this.AUDIT_FILTERS,
                sorts: [new DateSort({ for: 'modifiedOn' })]
            }).pipe(
                takeUntil(this.destroy$)
            ).subscribe(filters => {
                this.filters = filters;
                this.auditBuilderListService.changeFilter(filters);
                this.auditData$ = this.auditBuilderListService.auditBuilderData$;
            });
```

With switchmap (not working):

```
registerFilters$ = this.filterservice.registerFilters({
        key: this.FILTERS_KEY,
        filters: this.AUDIT_FILTERS,
        sorts: [new DateSort({ for: 'modifiedOn' })]
    });

    auditData$ = this.registerFilters$.pipe(
        switchMap((filters) => {
            this.filters = filters;
            this.auditBuilderListService.changeFilter(filters);
            return this.auditBuilderListService.auditBuilderData$;
        }),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    );
```

in service:

```
auditBuilderData$ = combineLatest([
    this.pageNumberSubject,
    this.filterAction$
]).pipe(
    switchMap(([currentPage, filterParameters]) => {
        return this.getAudits(filterParameters, currentPage, this.pageSize);
    }),
    shareReplay(1)
);
```

working version without switchmap:
auditData$: Observable;

```
registerFilters$ = this.filterservice.registerFilters({
    key: this.FILTERS_KEY,
    filters: this.AUDIT_FILTERS,
    sorts: [new DateSort({ for: 'modifiedOn' })]
}).pipe(
    tap(filters => {
        this.auditBuilderListService.setPage(1);
        this.filters = filters;
        this.auditBuilderListService.changeFilter(filters);         
    }),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
);

    this.registerFilters$
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe(filters => {
            this.auditData$ = this.auditBuilderListService.auditBuilderData$;
        });
```

But is there a better way to achieve the same?

Comment: is this.auditBuilderListService.auditBuilderData$; emitting?

Comment: yes, it is emitting

Comment: `this.filterservice.registerFilters` starts the flow and switches to `this.auditBuilderListService.auditBuilderData$`
if auditBuilderData$ emits after this (or repeats) it should work. Add a seperate subscription for `auditBuilderData$` and see if this is the case

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `auditBuilderListSerivce`, I'm assuming that invoking `changeFilter()` results in `auditBuilderData$` emitting a new value. If this is the case, it explains why your switchMap isn't working. You're returning `auditBuilderData$` too late because it emits it's value the moment you invoke `changeFilter()`.

As for solutions, you can either have `changeFilter()` return the value you wanted to emit (if that's possible). Another option is to reference and subscribe to `auditBuilderData$` separately.

```
registerFilters$ = this.filterservice.registerFilters({
  key: this.FILTERS_KEY,
  filters: this.AUDIT_FILTERS,
  sorts: [new DateSort({ for: 'modifiedOn' })],
}).pipe(
  tap(filters =>{
    this.filters = filters;
    this.auditBuilderListService.changeFilter(filters);
  }),
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
);

auditData$ = this.auditBuilderListService.auditBuilderData$;
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
);
```

When you have an active subscription to both observables, `registerFilters$` will invoke `changeFilter()` as a side effect which will cause `auditData$` to emit its new value.